# Sencha Touch 2.3.2: Use record data in pushed view

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm new to Sencha Touch and facing a problem with the tpl vars. I have the following code in my listview controller to push the next view:

```
onProjectListItemTap: function(list, index, target, record) {
    console.log('onProjectListItemTap');
    // load the detail
    var navigationView = list.up('navigationview');
    navigationView.push({
        title: record.data.projectName,
        xtype: 'projectdetail',
        record: record
    });
}
```

And this is the code in the 'projectdetail' view:

```
Ext.define('Antea.view.project.projectDetail', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',

xtype: 'projectdetail',

config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    items:[{
        xtype: 'panel',
        flex:1,
        store: 'projects',
        tpl:+
            '<div id="projectHeader" style="background-image: url({projectHeader})"></div>'+
            '<div class="projectItemHolder">'+
                '<h2 class="pageHeaderH2">{projectname}</h2>'+
            '</div>',
    }]
}
```

In this case the tpl vars do not work. When I take the tpl outside items and directly in the config it does work. I'm using sencha touch 2.3.2. I also found this post: [Sencha Touch TPL and ITEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569458/sencha-touch-tpl-and-item) which is very simular to my question, tried that but somehow that won't work for me (maybe because I'm a complete beginner). Hope anyone can help me out here!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you're mixing tpl and items, which doesn't seem to work. It would be best if you'd move your tpl out of the config object to keep it clean. Also I'm adding the template the way, they suggest it in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.Template):

```
Ext.define('Antea.view.project.projectDetail', {
  extend: 'Ext.Container', // use container instead of panels its one wrapper less

  xtype: 'projectdetail',

  config: {},

  // method will be called by the sencha framework
  initialize: function() {
      this.callParent();
      this.addTemplate();
      this.setData(this.getRecord().getData());
  },

  addTemplate: function() {

        t = new Ext.Template(
            '<div id="projectHeader" style="background-image: url({projectHeader})"></div>'+
            '<div class="projectItemHolder">'+
                '<h2 class="pageHeaderH2">{projectname}</h2>'+
            '</div>',

            {
                compiled: true, // compile immediately
                disableFormats: true // faster
            }
        );

    t.compile();
    this.setTpl(t);            
  }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your version makes a lot more sense to me! However, when I use your code it outputs nothing. Just an empty .x-inner div. Do you have any idea why? And what does the this.callParent(); function do?

Comment: I've adjusted the code in the initialize function. Hope that works -the data will be set one more time explicitly. If it doesn't work then check if this.getRecord() has a record with the correct structure. this.callParent() executes the code of the framework function initialize, to make sure that we don't miss important code fragments by overriding this method.